# (500 Internal Server Error])Flask Post request is causing the server Error [Flask]

Tags: python, html, heroku, flask

I have deployed a simple flask app (https://calc-cogs.herokuapp.com/) on Heroku but it is giving me the following error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

It gives me this error when I submit without any files but doesn't give me this error when I submit the files. But the thing is that I am returning similar things in both of those situations.

My python code is below which is giving me the error.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file_calculate():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if ('goodsold' not in request.files) or ('costingsheet' not in request.files) :
         return render_template('upload.html')
      good_sold = request.files['goodsold']
      costing_sheet = request.files['costingsheet']
      if good_sold and costing_sheet:
         calc=calc_cogs(good_sold,costing_sheet)
         return render_template('upload.html',COGS=calc.calculate()[0],Profit=calc.calculate()[1],items=calc.calculate()[2])
   else:
      return render_template('upload.html')
```

Html code where I am submitting a post request is here

```html
<form action = "{{ url_for('upload_file_calculate') }}" method = "POST" 
                    enctype = "multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 align="center" class="card-title">Goods Sold</h4>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="goodsold">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 align="center" class="card-title">Costing Sheet</h4>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="costingsheet">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer bg-primary">
                            <button align="center" type="submit" class="btn btn-block bg-white font-weight-bold">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I got the following error after tracing

```
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448235+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-27 04:08:14,447] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448260+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448265+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448268+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1835, in full_dispatch_request
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448271+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.finalize_request(rv)
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448273+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1850, in finalize_request
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448275+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.make_response(rv)
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448277+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1976, in make_response
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448280+00:00 app[web.1]: 'The view function did not return a valid response. The'
2019-06-27T04:08:14.448291+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
2019-06-27T04:08:14.449117+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.164.179.60 - - [27/Jun/2019:04:08:14 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://calc-cogs.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
```

But I did have a return statement as you can see in my python code. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: There is no return statement when `good_sold and costing_sheet` condition fails

Comment: inside `if request.method == 'POST':` you have two `if` but you don't have `else: return render_template(..)` or at least `return render_template(..)` so it may runs `return None` as default

Comment: @furas great it worked! Please put your comment as answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `if request.method == 'POST':` you have two `if` but you don't have

```
else: 
    return render_template(..)
```

or at least

```
return render_template(..)
```

so it may runs `return None` as default

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file_calculate():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if ('goodsold' not in request.files) or ('costingsheet' not in request.files) :
         return render_template('upload.html')
      good_sold = request.files['goodsold']
      costing_sheet = request.files['costingsheet']
      if good_sold and costing_sheet:
         calc=calc_cogs(good_sold,costing_sheet)
         return render_template('upload.html',COGS=calc.calculate()[0],Profit=calc.calculate()[1],items=calc.calculate()[2])

      return render_template(...)  # <--- need it instead of default `return None`

   else:
      return render_template('upload.html')
```

---

Probably you could write it in different way - using `and` instead of `or/not` - to have only one `return render_template('upload.html')` at the end.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file_calculate():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if ('goodsold' in request.files) and ('costingsheet' in request.files) :
          good_sold = request.files['goodsold']
          costing_sheet = request.files['costingsheet']
          if good_sold and costing_sheet:
             calc = calc_cogs(good_sold,costing_sheet)
             return render_template('upload.html', COGS=calc.calculate()[0], Profit=calc.calculate()[1], items=calc.calculate()[2])

   return render_template('upload.html')
```